# Unhandled expcetion(Xutility) C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012. I am writing a simple network game. Send/receve functions work fine. I don't understand why does program still throw the same exception at the same moment - when waitForOthers() function is completed. I toggled a lot of breakpoints and it looks like the program crashes after while loop is broken in this function BEFORE waitForOthersMove() in update fun.

Expcetion: 
"First-chance exception at 0x64D1CCC8 (msvcp110d.dll) in StatkiKlient.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x004B6CF4.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

xutility code which vs2012 points:

```
// MEMBER FUNCTIONS FOR _Container_base12
inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all()
{   // orphan all iterators
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
if (_Myproxy != 0)
    {   // proxy allocated, drain it
    _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);

    for (_Iterator_base12 **_Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
HERE -> *_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter) <- HERE
        (*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = 0;
    _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = 0;
    }
#endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
}
```

Here's the code:

"main.cpp":

```
#include "Client.h"

Client * client;

void clientLoop();

int main()
{
    client = new Client();

    clientLoop();

    return 0;
}

void clientLoop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        client->update();
    }
}
```

"Client.cpp":

```
#include "Client.h"


Client::Client()
{
    initialized = false;
    me = new Gamer();
    cnet = new ClientNetwork();
}


void Client::update()
{
    if(!initialized)
        waitForStart(); //here crashes



    waitForOthersMove();

 }


    void Client::waitForOthersMove()
    {
            Packet packet;

        char data[2000];

        int iResult = 0;

        std::cout<<"Oczekiwanie na przeciwnikow...\n\n";

    while(true)
    {
        iResult = cnet->receveData(data, sizeof(Packet));

        if(iResult < 0)
            continue;

        packet.deserialize(data);

        if(packet.packet_type = YOUR_MOVE)
        {
            //action
            break;
        }

    }
}



void Client::consoleInit() //only for tests
{
    Gamer set_up;

    Packet packet;

    char data[2000];

    set_up.nickname = "... " + me->id;

    set_up.ships[0].dir = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].size = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].x = 0;
    set_up.ships[0].y = 0;

    set_up.ships[0].dir = 1;
    set_up.ships[0].size = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].x = 10;
    set_up.ships[0].y = 15;

    set_up.ships[0].dir = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].size = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].x = 0;
    set_up.ships[0].y = 0;

    set_up.ships[0].dir = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].size = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].x = 0;
    set_up.ships[0].y = 0;

    set_up.ships[0].dir = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].size = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].x = 0;
    set_up.ships[0].y = 0;

    set_up.ships[0].dir = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].size = 2;
    set_up.ships[0].x = 0;
    set_up.ships[0].y = 0;

    packet.player = set_up;

    packet.serialize(data);

    cnet->sendMessage(data, sizeof(Packet));

}

void Client::gameInit()
{
    Packet packet; 

    char packet_data[2000];

    initialized = true;

    std::cout<<"My id: "<<me->id<<"\n";

    packet.packet_type = GAME_INIT_R;

    packet.serialize(packet_data);

    cnet->sendMessage(packet_data, sizeof(Packet));

    consoleInit();

    std::cout<<"wyslano game_init_r\n";
}



void Client::waitForStart()
{
    Packet packet;

    int messageLength = 0;


    printf("\nPołączono z serwerem. Oczekiwanie na pozostałych graczy...\n");

    cnet->testConnection();

    while(true)
    {

        messageLength = cnet->receveData(dataBuff, sizeof(Packet));

        if(messageLength < 0)
            continue;

        packet.deserialize(dataBuff);

        if(packet.packet_type = GAME_INIT)
        {
            me->id = packet.player.id;
            gameInit();
            printf("Initialized...");
            break;
        }
    }


} - after this parenthesis exception is thorw(i toggled breakpoint here and after this in update function)
```

Comment: What's `dataBuff`?  It would appear you're corrupting memory somewhere, perhaps by reading into a buffer that's too small or not allocated.

Comment: @Retired Ninja 
It is a buffer in Client class,  `char dataBuff[2000]`. I tried to use local variable but it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am initializing it, 2000 is enough - size of packet is 980 bytes :/

Comment: There isn't *nearly* enough code here to analyze this problem. Furthermore, your send-logic makes zero sense. You use `Packet::serialize()` to serialize the data into a raw buffer, then promptly send only `sizeof(Packet)` data *from* that buffer. Whats *that* ? `Packet::serialize() should return the number of bytes put in the data buffer, and *that* should be the send size. A similar (albeit different) logic should be used for receiving data. And you have the full stack trace in your VS debugger at the time the exception happens. Try reading that for more info on what you corrupted.

Comment: @WhozCraig serialization/deserialization:
`struct Packet
{
 unsigned int packet_type;
 Gamer player;

 void serialize(char * data) 
 {
        memcpy(data, this, sizeof(Packet));
    }

    void deserialize(char * data) 
 {
        memcpy(this, data, sizeof(Packet));
    }

};`

I always send/receve the same amout of bytes(sizeof(Packet)).

Comment: @bzbzbzbz then what is the point of `packet_data ` ? Why not just send via  `cnet->sendMessage((char*)&packet, sizeof(packet))` (which I don't advise, but thats all you're essentially doing anyway) ? And is Gamer a POD-type? does it have virtual methods? I suspect you're read-code is blasting over a vtable, but again, without *more code* its simply impossible to tell. vtc.